# Not submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My form will validate on the client side but I'm trying to figure out why its not validating on the server side. I don't have my php complete but its not even bringing up the POST request in my console saying its submitting the form to the server.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

/*
* Validate the form when it is submitted
*/
var validateform = $("#newArticleForm").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
            ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted.'
            : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted.';
            $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
            $('.box .content').alertBox(message, {type: 'warning', icon: true, noMargin: false});
            $('.box .content .alert').css({
                width: '100%',
                margin: '0',
                borderLeft: 'none',
                borderRight: 'none',
                borderRadius: 0
            });
        } else {
            $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
        }
    },
    showErrors : function(errorMap, errorList) {
        this.defaultShowErrors();
        var self = this;
        $.each(errorList, function() {
            var $input = $(this.element);
            var $label = $input.parent().find('label.error').hide();
            $label.addClass('red');
            $label.css('width', '');
            $input.trigger('labeled');
            $label.fadeIn();
        });
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var dataString = $('#newArticleForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/kowmanager/dashboard/articleSubmit',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function(data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
                    $('.box .content').alertBox(data.message, {type: 'warning', icon: true, noMargin: false});
                    $('.box .content .alert').css({
                        width: '',
                        margin: '0',
                        borderLeft: 'none',
                        borderRight: 'none',
                        borderRadius: 0
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
                    $('.box .content').alertBox(data.message, {type: 'success', icon: true, noMargin: false});
                    $('.box .content .alert').css({
                        width: '',
                        margin: '0',
                        borderLeft: 'none',
                        borderRight: 'none',
                        borderRadius: 0
                    }); 
                    $(':input','#newArticleForm')
                    .not(':submit, :button, :hidden, :reset')
                    .val('');  
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

});
```

Controller:

```
function articleSubmit()
{
    $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'unproccessed');
    $outputMsg = '';
    // Sets validation rules for the login form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title',
        'trim|required|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category',
        'integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isSticky', 'Is Sticky',
        'integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comments', 'Allow Comments',
        'integer');    

    // Checks to see if login form was submitted properly
    if (!$this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $outputArray['message'] =
            'There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!';
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'validate', 'id' => 'newArticleForm'); ?>
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('', $attributes) ?>
                <div class="content no-padding">
                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Title', 'title'); ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php echo form_input('title', '', 'class="required"'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Category', 'category'); ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php echo form_dropdown('category', $categories, '', 'class="required"'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Is Sticky', 'sticky'); ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php 
                                                            $options = array(
                                                                        ''   => 'Please Select An Option',
                                                                        '0'  => 'No',
                                                                        '1'  => 'Yes',
                                                                     );
                                                            ?><?php echo form_dropdown('sticky', $options, '', 'class="required"'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Allow Comments', 'comments'); ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php 
                                                            $options = array(
                                                                        ''   => 'Please Select An Option',
                                                                        '0'  => 'No',
                                                                        '1'  => 'Yes',
                                                                     );
                                                            ?><?php echo form_dropdown('comments', $options, '', 'class="required"'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Date Comments Expire', 'datetime'); ?>

                        <div>
                            <input id="datetime" type="datetime" class="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Status', 'status'); ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php 
                                                            $options = array(
                                                                        ''   => 'Please Select An Option',
                                                                        '0'  => 'Inactive',
                                                                        '1'  => 'Active',
                                                                     );
                                                            ?><?php echo form_dropdown('status', $options, '', 'class="required"'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Image', 'file'); ?>
                        <div>
                            <?php echo form_upload('file', '', 'class="required"'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Permalink', 'permalink'); ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php echo form_input('permalink', '', 'class="required"'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <?php echo form_label('Article', 'article'); ?><?php $attributes = array('name' => 'article', 'cols' => '30', 'rows' => '5', 'id' => 'article', 'class' => 'required') ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php echo form_textarea($attributes); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End of .content -->

                <div class="actions">
                    <div class="actions-left">
                        <?php echo form_reset(array('id' => 'reset', 'name' => 'reset'), 'Reset'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="actions-right">
                        <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'name' => 'submit'), 'Submit'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End of .actions -->
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

EDIT:

I have other forms that use this jquery as well but wondering if anyone had any additional ideas?

Comment: did you try adding `.complete()` and `.error()` handlers to `$.ajax` request? what do they return?

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer to this issue... and it drove me nuts so I am happy to help you with this one :))

Codeigniter works in a very special way with POST requests. If you do this but instead use a GET request you will see it works fine... so what's going on?

Codeigniter has a crsf token to make sure you POST your data in a safe way.
So make sure you send this crsf value with the rest of your data.

I will give you an example, this is what my POST ajax + codeigniter looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        data: {
            somevalue : somevalue,
            csrf_test_name  : $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
        },
```

...

As you can see, your crsf value is stored in a cookie. I use the jquery plugin cookie helper, but feel fry to use any other plugin.

However, **keep in mind that the name 'csrf_test_name' is always expected by codeigniter when making a POST request**

Have a nice day!

---

For those who want to read more a bout this, this is what I am talking about:
http://aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20

Comment: odd because I have other forms that I use that work just fine with the way I have it above but with this form it doesn't work right for some reason.

Comment: In your config file, is your global_xss_filtering set to true?

Comment: Then csrf_test_name is necessary I believe, although I don't understand how your other forms are sent using the POST method without a csrf_test_name value :S

Comment: Well, if I were you I would try changing your current AJAX type from POST to GET (both in the jquery and in the controller code). If it works with GET then you know it is the crsf for sure, if it doesn't I would suggest taking a look at the link, maybe using a relative link (site_url from HTML helper)